# Adding Areas to an MVC application - any gotchas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP.net MVC application that has been in Production for a while. I would like to add a new Admin section to the application which I wanted to do by creating a new Area. I'm just curious what sorts of things I might need to be aware of when adding this new area.

Specifically:

1. Is there any existing functionality that is likely to break by adding the new Area?
2. What is the best way to make an Area restricted to a certain group? Base controller class?
3. Any other things (common mistakes, etc.) that I need to be aware of that adding a new Area will affect?

Comment: I'd use an Area for this. I'd also add unit tests for all existing routes to make sure they don't break when you add your new area and its routes.

Comment: Are you already using Areas for other sections?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Nope, this will be the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to be careful of is naming collisions - if you have 2 controllers with the same name but in different areas you need to add namespaces, as described here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx

To restrict the admin area to a certain group, you could use the Authorize attribute with Roles on the Admin controller(s), as desribed here: [ASP.NET MVC 3 - How to restrict areas in an efficient way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913215/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-restrict-areas-in-an-efficient-way)